# DFT python with time base

Tags: python, dft

As a beginner in programming, I have been working on DFT case in python which I have to compute a program and find the real and imaginary value of cosine function (f(t) = cos*2*phi*12.5*t) with time delta = 0.01s at the 100 points.
If I have to define the function, the value of 12.5 is the frequency or something else?
Does anyone ever compute this one also before?
Need some advice, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `numpy`, `numpy.cos` and `numpy.r_`. Imaginary numbers are written like that: `1+1j`

Comment: So, for the imaginary numbers, we can use 1+1j? I just read from NumPy lib, there's another way we can execute from np.imag, is it true also?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @wshn  `np.imag()` returns the imaginary part of your number so `np.imag(1+2j) -> 2`

Comment: Okay, well thank you for the help. I got it. Since the day before, I tried to change some commands and it worked.